# Instance variable in Spring Service

Tags: java, spring, caching, dictionary

I have following Spring Service

```
@Service
class FeatureTogglesImpl implements FeatureToggles {

    private final FeatureToggleRepository featureToggleRepository;
    private       Map<String, Feature>    featuresCache;

    @Autowired
    public FeatureTogglesImpl(final FeatureToggleRepository featureToggleRepository) {
        this.featureToggleRepository = featureToggleRepository;
        this.featuresCache = loadAllFromRepository();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void enable(Feature feature) {
        Feature cachedFeature = loadFromCache(feature);
        cachedFeature.enable();
        featureToggleRepository.save(cachedFeature);
        onFeatureToggled();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(Feature feature) {
        return loadFromCache(feature).isEnabled();
    }

    private Feature loadFromCache(Feature feature) {
        checkNotNull(feature);
        return featuresCache.get(feature.getKey());
    }

    private Map<String, Feature> loadAllFromRepository() {
        return Maps.uniqueIndex(featureToggleRepository.findAll(), new Function<Feature, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Feature feature) {
                return feature.getKey();
            }
        });
    }

    void onFeatureToggled() {
        featuresCache = loadAllFromRepository();
    }

}
```

As you can see,I store loaded features into `featuresCache`, so that when client calls `isEnabled()` it is loading according feature from the cache.

There is a managed bean, who manages toggling the feature,

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@Scope("view")
public class FeatureTogglesManager {

    @Autowired
    private FeatureToggles featureToggles;

    @Secured({"ROLE_FEATURE_TOGGLES_EDIT"})
    public String enable(Feature feature) {
        featureToggles.enable(feature);
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I call `enable()` from `AdminFeatureTogglesManager` , I can see proper feature toggled, and cache pre-populated.

I have another service, which actually uses `FeatureToggles.isEnabled()` service

```
@Service
class ProductServieImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private FeatureToggles featureToggles;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void loadProducts() {
        if (featureToggles.isEnabled(NewProducts.insance())) {
            loadNewProducts();
            return;
        }
        loadOldProducts();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `featureToggles.isEnabled()` from this service always returns old instance from the cache, and when I debug the `FeatureTogglesImpl`, I do not see my pre-populated cache, although after toggle I could see correct/updated cache.

Isn't FeatureTogglesImpl supposed to be a singletong, so that if I change instance variable, it changes everywhere? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your code is not thread safe, other threads can see old cache

Comment: The cache is also not transactional: if the transaction toggling a feature rollbacks, the cache and the database will be inconsistent. This looks like premature optimization to me. Your database should be more than fast enough, without an application cache.